# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Array of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have created an array of arraylists which has a size of 45.  I am getting an ArrayOutOfBoundException for some reason.

Here's where I'm getting the error:

```
    String temp;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str1);
    while(sc.hasNext())
    {
        temp = sc.next();
        int len = temp.length();
        if(len > 0)
            wordsByLen[len - 1].add(temp);  //throwing the error here with exception of 59
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: where is wordsByLen defined

Comment: What assures you that `temp.length()` will never be higher than 45? You are reading a String for what I can see

Comment: I defined wordsByLen in the constructor of the class.

Comment: I can see that you have an assumption that temp.length() will return value between 0 to 44. Is that true? This might be causing the issue.

Comment: try to print the value of `len` before the `if` condition and see what values you are getting

Comment: So I should do:  if(temp.length() < MAX && temp.length() > 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised the array `wordsByLen` correctly ? I suspect not.

I think what you need to do is initialise the array *with the correct length*, and then with a collection for every possible word length. e.g. (in pseudocode)

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDLENGTH; i++) {
   wordsByLen[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

I would perhaps use a `Map<Integer,List<String>>` instead. You'll have to initialise it in a similar way, but it would be a more reliable mechanism. You wouldn't have an arbitrary limit on the maximum number of characters you can record words for.

Comment: Yes.  I did that in the constructor.  Before I did that, I was getting a NullPointerException at the same line.  I just didn't include the code because I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: You're finding a word of 59 chars when you only have capacity to store info for words of up to 45 chars. The above solution (using a Map) will circumvent this problem

Comment: My assignment says that the limit has to be 45.  Thank you for your suggestion but that won't work for me.